# MonoDevelop: Edit Key Bindings XML?

Tags: xml, monodevelop, config, key-bindings, remap

I am wondering where to edit the keybindings for MonoDevelop in text/XML format. 
I am in a situation where I switch regularly between a Mac and a PC, and the copy/paste function between the two is driving me crazy. I have physically remapped my Windows keyboard, so all of the functions are as close as I can get them except for copy/paste.

When I try to edit the key binding for copy in the editor window, I'm trying to set it to Alt + C (which physically/visually maps to the same location as Command + C on my keyboard). But when I hit this key combo to save it, that command is hard mapped to "cancel" in Windows 7's OS, so it cancels out of the dialog window before I can successfully remap this config.

I haven't been able to find, after some googling, where the config file is for this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS, you can find your custom keybindings in `~/Library/MonoDevelop-3.0/KeyBindings/Custom.mac-kb.xml`

On WIndows, it'll be something like `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MonoDevelop-3.0\KeyBindings\Custom.kb.xml`

Comment: it appears that changing copy to alt+c is not possible. i found a way around the problem by writing the words "Alt+C" in somewhere else and pasting them in the input area. The input would not take.  I was able to reset copy to any other number of combinations, but not Alt+C. 

Also, adding a line in the XML file setting they key binding of Copy to shortcut="Alt+C" did not work either.

Comment: in fact, editing the entries in this file for other commands that are known to work has no effect.

Comment: AH! I've found the solution. I entered the line:
<binding command="MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.EditCommands.Copy" shortcut="Alt+C" />

Previously, I was using "TextEditorCommands" instead of "EditCommands". This made all the difference. Solved! My life just got much easier!

Comment: How were you trying to enter Alt+C in the input area? Just hit Alt and then hit C. Don't try to type "Alt+C", just hit the keys :-)

Comment: right, but if you hit alt once, it moves focus to the menu bar. if you hit alt and c at the same time it cancels what you're doing. either way, focus is moved away from the desired field